# javascript remove text with double inverted comma not working

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json object in a table like below

```
filter: {where: { AND:[{gender: {IN: "Female"}},{age: {LTE: 44}}]}, relativeDateRange: 90}
```

which I am fetching and need to change, By removing some of the text.
The new json object will look like below

```
{"filter": {"where": {"gender": {"IN": "Female"}, "age": {"LTE": 54}},"relativeDateRange": 90}}
```

One way of doing that is to stringify the object and replacing the keyword,
which in my "theory" should work. however by any mean I am not able to replace ('{"AND":') to blank.
The issue is the keyword contains double inverted comma.

below is the code:
s is the json object which contains the wrong json.

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(s);
var t1 = stringified.replace("}{",", ").replace("}}]}","}}").replace('{"AND":', '')
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(t1);
console.log("new json:" +jsonObject);
```

The text which does not have double inverted comma is getting replaced. 
Even using regex or escape character is not helping.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

One option you can try is to use the replacer function which is a parameter in JSON.stringify:

```
// Your initial filter object
const filter = {filter: {where: { AND:[{gender: {IN: "Female"}},{age: {LTE: 44}}]}, relativeDateRange: 90}};

// Define your replacer function:
const replacer = (name, value) => {
    if (name === 'where') {
        const array = value['AND'];
        // Merge array elements or alter your output in any other way
        return Object.assign({}, array[0], array[1]);
    }
    return value;
}

// The resulting output
console.log(JSON.stringify(filter, replacer, 2));
```

will produce the following output:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "where": {
      "gender": {
        "IN": "Female"
      },
      "age": {
        "LTE": 44
      }
    },
    "relativeDateRange": 90
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the colon that's throwing off your text replacement statement. How about replacing the "AND" string first, before you complicate it by replacing the curley braces? It should not otherwise effect your other replacements.

```
var t1 = stringified.replace("AND:[","").replace("}{",", ").replace("}}]}","}}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The final resolution or more precisely the problem i figure out was, 
When a josn is stringified, Its add '\' before every word. As for example when below json is stringified.

```
filter: {where: { AND:[{gender: {IN: "Female"}},{age: {LTE: 44}}]}, relativeDateRange: 90}
```

it gives the output as

```
\filter: {\where: { \AND ....
```

And the simple resolution was to use replace with double backslash as below.

```
var t1 = stringified.replace('{\\"AND\\":','').replace(/}{/g,",").replace("}}},","}},").replace('{/"/":','')
```